# asp.net mvc treeview helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview

I am working in asp.net MVC (Razor). I want to use treeview in my webpage. Is there any treeview helper in Razor? Or if not, then how to use/integrate asp.net control to asp.net MVC(Razor) ?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to use classic ASP.NET Controls in a Razor view, however there are lots of equivalent treeview extensions for ASP.NET MVC available.

For example: [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/community/promos/freestuff.aspx)